# How to iterate through a list of coordinates and calculate distance between them in Python

Tags: python

I have list that has 20 coordinates (x and y coordinates). I can calculate the distance between any two coordinates, but I have a hard time writing an algorithm that will iterate through the list and calculate the distance between the first node and every other node. for example,

```
ListOfCoordinates = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]
```

In this case I need a for loop that will interate the list and calculate the distance between the first coordinate and the second coordinates, distance between first coordinate and third coordinate, etc. I am in need of an algorithm to help me out, then I will transform it into a python code. Thanks

Thanks for ll the feedback. It's been helpful.

Comment: This is basic - one loop inside another. What's so hard?

Comment: @frostnational that solution is poor as it will make a copy of the list each time and remove the current item increasing the runtime

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you need something combinatorics-oriented ("I need first and second, then first and third, then...") chances are the `itertools` module has what you need.

```
from math import hypot

def distance(p1,p2):
    """Euclidean distance between two points."""
    x1,y1 = p1
    x2,y2 = p2
    return hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

from itertools import combinations

list_of_coords = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]

[distance(*combo) for combo in combinations(list_of_coords,2)]
Out[29]: 
[2.8284271247461903,
 5.656854249492381,
 8.48528137423857,
 11.313708498984761,
 14.142135623730951,
 2.8284271247461903,
 5.656854249492381,
 8.48528137423857,
 11.313708498984761,
 2.8284271247461903,
 5.656854249492381,
 8.48528137423857,
 2.8284271247461903,
 5.656854249492381,
 2.8284271247461903]
```

edit: Your question is a bit confusing.  Just in case you only want the first point compared against the other points:

```
from itertools import repeat

pts = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]

[distance(*pair) for pair in zip(repeat(pts[0]),pts[1:])]
Out[32]: 
[2.8284271247461903,
 5.656854249492381,
 8.48528137423857,
 11.313708498984761,
 14.142135623730951]
```

But usually in this type of problem you care about *all* the combinations so I'll leave the first answer up there.

Comment: This is the most correct solution. Methods which remove the current item from a copy of the original list will inflate the runtime for large datasets.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to `itertools` (and `operator` with it). Powerful and useful tool for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a single line script to do this. The following script did the job for me.

```
import numpy as np
yd = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]
distances_matrix = np.array([np.linalg.norm((item*np.ones((len(yd),len(item))))-yd,axis=1) for item in yd])

print(distances_matrix)

output:
[[ 0.          2.82842712  5.65685425  8.48528137 11.3137085  14.14213562]
 [ 2.82842712  0.          2.82842712  5.65685425  8.48528137 11.3137085 ]
 [ 5.65685425  2.82842712  0.          2.82842712  5.65685425  8.48528137]
 [ 8.48528137  5.65685425  2.82842712  0.          2.82842712  5.65685425]
 [11.3137085   8.48528137  5.65685425  2.82842712  0.          2.82842712]
 [14.14213562 11.3137085   8.48528137  5.65685425  2.82842712  0.        ]]


#Distance between coordinates with indices 2 and 4
print(distance_matrix[2,4])
output:
5.656854249492381
```

Note: Here, I am using the Euclidean distance calculated only using Numpy. This solution should work for most cases. But it isn't recommended when the array/list is too large and it is not viable to make a copy of the same in the memory.

Comment: Without any calculation I can say that the distance from `1, 2` to `3, 4` is substantially less than `20`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, Klaus D. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: l = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]

In [7]: def distance(a, b):                              
    return (a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1])
   ...: 

In [8]: for m in l[1:]:                                  
    print(distance(l[0], m))
   ...:     
(-2, -2)
(-4, -4)
(-6, -6)
(-8, -8)
(-10, -10)
```

Of course you would have to adapt `distance` to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `distance` function that takes two tuples, which are coordinate pairs, as parameters.

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)
```

Since you only need an algorithm to calculate distances between the *first* node and every other node, create a loop that cycles through each of your `ListOfCoordinates`:

```
for i in range(1, len(ListOfCoordinates)):
    # you can use print or return, depending on your needs
    print distance(ListOfCoordinates[0], ListOfCoordinates[i])
```